# css: center 2 floating divs using jQuery UI classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI classes to create a master Div that holds 2 floating divs whose widths should 50%.

**Problem:**
As soon as I add `div.ui-widget-header` , Divs appear on top of each other, I want divs to be side by side so Both `ui-widget-header` merge seamlessly at 50% width.
If I change width to 49% for both then it works but then both `ui-widget-header`s have gap.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/jsR96/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<div class="ui-widget-content container-div1" style="width: 50%;">
    <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
        header1
    </div>  
    Div 1 text
 </div> 
<div class="ui-widget-content container-div2" style="width: 50%;">
    <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
        header2
    </div>
    Div 2 text
 </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{font-size:.8em;width:100%!important;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0}
.container .ui-widget-header{border:none;font-size:11px}
.container-div1{float:left;border:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.container-div2{float:left;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;margin:0;padding:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is a border on `div2` this then makes it uneven. They should be 50/50 but as the border is say 1px its making it 50/50.01 (or something like that) this forces the div to not fit and move under the other.

Try putting `border: none;` on both you should see they sit next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy just remove the border on the last element

see this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jsR96/4/)** for your result.

```
.container-div1,
.container-div2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float:left;
  border : none;
}
```

This is the css change anything else is the same

Comment: Actually i knew border was the issue. But i needed the divider border :) and iw anted width to be in perncentages .. But 49.XX leaves a gap.So iAssume i will have to adjust width via js

Comment: easy fix make an inner div in the first element position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 100%; left:0; hacky but it does work remember to make the parent div position:relative;

Comment: .Can you provide Fiddle example ?